# Upload images from folder to slides directly

Tags: windows, google-api, google-docs

I wish to write a script that upload all images in google slides from a folder. This entails there should be one image per slide. I wish to do so in a pre-existing google slides doc, whereby I specify the starting slide. I don't know much about google-api. Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code - what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mogsdad I want a starting code or approach. Used python, but can't simply do it. It can only extract the images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to programmatically edit Google slides

Comment: Does using app script do any good. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/   .Reference-https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/gW5tVYUEcDY

Comment: Do you see "slides" as part of the supported list on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/   there is also a feature request.  https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573